# Giving a user another try to enter the correct input without quit

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to take a number from inputtxt (which is Text widget) , I need to test the input ; if it's not a number the program should gives the user another chance to enter the correct input. I did this ; the problem is the warning message shows but the program proceeds . I need a way to give the user another chance without quitting the program.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image  
from tkinter import messagebox
import subprocess
from tkinter import filedialog
window = Tk()
window.title("Test")
window.geometry('650x400')
frame = Frame(window)
# Gets both half the screen width/height and window width/height
positionRight = 350
positionDown = 100
# Positions the window in the center of the page.
window.geometry("+{}+{}".format(positionRight, positionDown))
inputtxt2 = Text(window, height = 1, width =24,bg = "light yellow")
inputtxt2.pack()
inputtxt2.place(x=325, y=108)
def run_button():
    num_of_compare_points= inputtxt2.get('1.0', 'end-1c').strip().replace("\n","")
    if not (num_of_compare_points.isnumeric()):
        messagebox.showwarning("Warning","Please Enter a Valid Integer Value for Group Size!")
    print (int(num_of_compare_points)+1)
runButton = tkinter.Button(window, text ="Run",font = "Times", command = run_button)
runButton.pack()
runButton.place(x=260, y=320)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you want the user to enter the file_path until the correct path is entered?

Comment: yes @Art. And I still want to show the warning if the path is incorrect

Comment: So what's the problem? What's the quit function doing there?

Comment: quit() quits the program at all . I don't want to quit , what I want is to give the user many chances till he writes the correct path

Comment: and if I remove quit() , I have File not found error

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''

Comment: provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I thik it's minimal , only text field and getting the file path from text field

Comment: This example isn't a [mcve] because it's not complete. We don't know how you're calling this code - is it in a loop? An event handler? Called when the program first starts?

Comment: edited . @BryanOakley

Comment: It's still not a complete example.

Comment: Updated. Check Please . @BryanOakley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really clear what your problem is. If the data is invalid, you can just return from the function without doing anything.

```
def run_button():
    num_of_compare_points= inputtxt2.get('1.0', 'end-1c').strip().replace("\n","")
    if not (num_of_compare_points.isnumeric()):
        messagebox.showwarning("Warning","Please Enter a Valid Integer Value for Group Size!")
        return
    print (int(num_of_compare_points)+1)
```